# Javascript pop-up windows

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm making a filter with javascript, but the problems are whenever I type in something in the filter, the javascript window just pop-up, even before it starts to filter. My plan is to pop-up the window when I found nothing matches the input, but the problem is either nothing is going to change, or the window pop up before it filters it.
The HTML code:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %} 
{% block content %}
<div style="text-align:center"><h1>查找患者</h1></div>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
  event.preventDefault()
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="请输入患者姓名..." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  {% for item in values %}
  <div class=content-section">
    <li><a href="/patient-info/{{ item.name }}">患者姓名: {{ item.name }} | 性别: {{ item.gender }} | 年龄: {{ item.age }} | 手机号: {{ item.number }}</a></li><br>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else { 
            li[i].style.display = 'none'
             alert("找不到此病人"); 
        }
    }
}
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change You logic as below,

```
function myFunction() {
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
// Adding a new flag variable to verify whether a match found or not
var nothingFound = true;
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
        // you found something , so set nothingFound to false
        nothingFound = false;
    } else { 
        li[i].style.display = 'none'
        // Remove the below alert
        // alert("找不到此病人"); 
    }
}
// Raise Alert only when nothingFound  is still true
if(nothingFound ) {
  alert("找不到此病人"); 
}
```

}

Simple logics may be tough during initial stage. Try to work on a story/strategy like algorithm will help us in initial stage. Later we wont need that.